# EventBus Xamaring. Custom method of activity not found using reflection

Tags: xamarin, reflection, binding, event-bus

I've added EventBus as a binding library in my Xamarin Android project.
I can compile without errors but when I'm trying to register, I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the code for the activity

```
[Activity(Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher"]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        

        EventBus.Default.Register(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        EventBus.Default.Unregister(this);
    }

    [Subscribe]
    public void onEvent(DeviceConnectionEvent my_event)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultVal, Intent data)
    {

        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            wifiManagerInstance.onNetworkDataReceived();
        }

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultVal, data);

    }
}
```

It looks like my method is not being detected when eventbus uses reflection

```
methods = findState.clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Other methods of the activity are detected as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a binding library for `EventBus`, I couldn't test it, but
you could check to see if your package is imported correctly when you use `[Subscribe]` attribute.

Here you should use `org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;` rather than `com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;`

I think you could also use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to do what you want.